# ERROR SSIS SSDT "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"

Tags: sql-server, ssis

He revisado un montón de foros , preguntas y respuestas y nada me ayuda
resulta que estoy programando `ETL` en **VS2017** con `SSDT` (`SSIS`)

Tengo origen de dato `OLE DB` a `ORACLE` con destino a `ADO.NET` **(sql server 2016)**
hasta el hace unos días podía desplegar la vista de tablas en ambos objetos
origen y destino.
Hoy me aparecieron actualizar unos complementos extensiones de **VS** que tienen que ver con `SSIS` (no recuerdo cuales) eran 2. (pero cabe destacar que son extensiones de **VS 2017**)

después de esos no me funcionó nada, ni los proyectos ni nada.
reparé el `SSDT` y volvió a cargar los proyectos pero sin poder revisar las tablas ya sean de origen o destino 
[image: error en VS2017 SSDT (SSIS)]

Además también aparece el error en `sql`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿>lguna idea de que puedo hacer?
De antemano gracias.

**NOTA si ingreso manualmente el nombre de las tablas no ocasiona error, funciona la ETL normal.**

Comment: puedes desplegar el detalle del error del Management Studio?

Comment: si, este es el mensaje
===================================

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (ObjectExplorer)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.FullTextMenuHandler.GetMenuItems()

Comment: Ayer probé con desintalar sql completo, y el ssdt de Visual Studio, y volver a instalar todo nuevamente.
Resulta que el problema en VS 2017 del despliegue de tabla ahora funciona, todo sigue funcionando OK, pero aun en sql server management studio al dar click derecho sobre alguna tabla sigue desplegando el error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" aunque al darle ok al botón puedo ver todo bien

Comment: y probaste instalando nuevamente el Management Studio de manera independiente? es muy raro tener un error de UX por lo que no me extrañaría que el archivo de instalación este corrupto.

Comment: desintalé todo, y volvi a instalar y sigue el mismo problema... y descargue los instaladores denuevo limpio y todo, sigue el problema.

Comment: Alguna idea de que puede ser? @arce-est